# In react-native: How to dismiss dropdown menu View, on clicking screen outside of this dropdown menu inside functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

> I uses functional component to create below dropdown View, which I want to dismiss it on clicking anywhere in screen outside of this View.

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you please share  your code, so that I can help you?

Comment: I got some hint like: using onStartShouldSetResponder method, but not getting proper way how shall I use.

Answer (score 0):

use this package

react-native-element-dropdown
here is the link

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-element-dropdown

I'm also using this package, a small video is also below.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b_QREC4JiMI5YCwFHPLsnraSoqvDrJ5C/view

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I need only logic for dismissible of dropdown view from outside.,

Comment: Share your code, I will give you a hint accordingly...